# Issues with Wordpress fresh install on RPi

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, raspberry-pi

1) I cannot change themes. It asks me for an FTP login. I changed the connection type to direct in the config, but it doesn't change anything. Although I seem to be entering the right credentials, it says error 21, can't connect to server.

2) The webpage displays correctly on the RPi, but when I try to access the website on another computer on my local network, the webpage doesn't display properly. The best description I can give is that it doesn't have any pictures or formatting.

3) When accessing on the same computer as issue #2, the webpages don't route properly. I visit the webpage using (example) `192.168.1.22`. It goes to the webpage. Then when I click on Login, it goes to `localhost/wp-admin.php` instead of `192.168.1.22/wp-admin.php` and I am not sure why.

Picture: http://screencast.com/t/7jEgzDGZQ

Comment: Can you edit your post and add some pictures?

Comment: @Fralec I fixed issues 2 and 3. Do you still want pictures?

Comment: If the other solutions, don't help you, yes please.

Comment: @Fralec post edited

Comment: You tried connection with a tool like FileZilla?

Comment: @Fralec No. How would that help me install plugins/themes? Especially when I have access to the computer already running it.

Comment: It's to try if you FTP server work. And you can also install plugins/themes with an FTP client.

Comment: @Fralec Alright I'll give it a try

Comment: @Fralec Gave it a try. Returned with Authentication failed.
Critical error: Could not connect to server

Comment: You setup a FTP server? If you cannot connect with FileZilla it will not work with WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more, I can give you a bit of insight that will hopefully help.

1. Sounds like a file permissions issue. If you want to be able to
   update/add themes from the admin back-end, you need to give file
   permissions to the web-server user/user-group (www-data many times)
   Also, the inability to connect via ftp, could be a firewall setting
   in linux. you'll have to do some research based on your distro.
2. This is most likely in relation to #3. Basically, your client (the
   other computer) is looking for your CSS on localhost and it doesn't
   exist.
3. Try this. Use your favorite tool (like wp-cli) to do a
   search-replace in the DB for localhost to your ip. Then try all
   these things.

Hopefully this helps you get on the right path!

- Cheers!

Comment: Any recommendation for how to fix the file permission issue?

Comment: Thank you, you're reply fixed Issue 2 and 3 for me. Issue one still persists though.

Comment: It looks like FTP is trying to connect to Localhost:21. Is there any way I can change it to the IP:21 like I just did for the website routing?

Comment: If it is asking for FTP in the WordPress admin area, you have a permissions issue. I can't get the link for you right now but look up digitalocean Wordpress permissions and see what you find. Basically, there is a user on your Linux install for your web server. Usually, that defaults to www-data for nginx I believe. That user must have permission to interact with the file structure on your server. So you need that user to own "wp-content" folder and its au folders and files. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked for you. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

**issue #1:** change file permisions and give wordpress write access

**issue #2:** as described in issue #3 localhost is used as address base, so only the RPi can load images and styles correctly. You can change the site url in admin under settings.

**issue #3:** see issue #2

Comment: Okay I'll look into it. What should I be using for my write access command. I know I transferred the directory to the pi user, but that didn't seem to help.
I'll look around the admin settings to see if I can find that setting.

Comment: Thank you, you're reply fixed Issue 2 and 3 for me. Issue one still persists though.

Comment: It looks like FTP is trying to connect to Localhost:21. Is there any way I can change it to the IP:21 like I just did for the website routing?